# Poly function from monomorphic functions that operate on coproduct

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm working on an API that should enable to build a shapeless `Poly1` function dynamically from standard monomorphic functions that operate on types of some coproduct.

The goal is to expose a simple method that receives a function as:

```
type FooCoproduct = Foo :+: Bar :+: CNil
def addF[E](f: E => E)(implicit ev: Inject[FooCoproduct, E]) = ???
```

and accumulate these functions in order to build a total Poly1 function covering all types in the coproduct. The evidence `ev` here is to force that the type paremeter `E` is a type in the coproduct.

After testing several approaches, including generic derivation of typeclasses, the most promising one has led me to accumulate these monomorphic functions in an `HList` and try to resolve the one that applies by means of a `Selector`. This is probably better understood by example:

```
object CoproductSample extends App {

  import shapeless.{ :+:, CNil, Coproduct, HList, HNil, Poly1 }
  import shapeless.ops.coproduct.Inject
  import shapeless.ops.hlist.Selector

  class Builder[A <: Coproduct] {

    def accum[B](f: B => B, hl: HList)(implicit ev: Inject[A, B]) = f :: hl

    class PolyBuilder[L <: HList](hl: L) extends Poly1 {
      implicit def run[T](implicit ev: Selector[L, T => T]) = 
        at[T](hl.select[T => T])
    }

  }

  type Cop = Int :+: String :+: CNil

  val builder = new Builder[Cop]

  val hl1 = builder.accum((i: Int) => i + 1, HNil)
  val hl2 = builder.accum((s: String) => s + "one", hl1)

  object pf extends builder.PolyBuilder(hl2)

  val rInt = Coproduct[Cop](10).fold(pf)
  val rStr = Coproduct[Cop]("ten").fold(pf)
}
```

This code doesn't compile with the message:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter folder:     
shapeless.ops.coproduct.Folder[CoproductSample.pf.type, CoproductSample.Cop]
```

I suppose that I need to provide a `Selector[L, T => T]` where `L` is the type of the accumulated `HList` but I can't come up with the way to do this. On the other hand, I have the feeling that there must be a simpler solution to my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

After doing some more research I've come up with a solution that almost works. Unfortunately I'm not able to track the result type properly.

```
object CoproductSample {
  import shapeless.{ CNil, Coproduct, HList, HNil, Inl, Inr, Poly2, ::, :+: }

  // Accumulates ordinary functions from A => A in an HList
  def accum[A, L <: HList](f: A => A, hl: L): (A => A) :: L = f :: hl

  // A poly2 function that evaluates some monomorphic function present in
  // an HList for certain value that satifies the signature of this function
  object PolyEval extends Poly2 {
    implicit def hnilCase[A]: Case.Aux[A, HNil, Option[A]] =
      at[A, HNil]((a, l) => None)

    implicit def hheadCaseSuccess[A, T <: HList]: Case.Aux[A, (A => A) :: T, Option[A]] =
      at[A, (A => A) :: T]((a: A, l: (A => A) :: T) => Option(l.head(a)))

    implicit def hheadCaseFail[A, H, T <: HList](
        implicit tail: Case.Aux[A, T, Option[A]]
    ): Case.Aux[A, (H => H) :: T, Option[A]] =
      at[A, (H => H) :: T]((a: A, l: (H => H) :: T) => PolyEval(a, l.tail))
  }

  // A poly2 function that uses `PolyEval` for evaluating a value present in
  // a coproduct against an HList of monomorphic functions
  object PolyEvalCop extends Poly2 {
    implicit def cnilCase[A <: CNil, L <: HList]: Case.Aux[A, L, Option[A]] =
      at[A, L]((a, l) => sys.error("Impossible!"))

    implicit def cconsCase[H, T <: Coproduct, L <: HList](
        implicit head: PolyEval.Case.Aux[H, L, Option[H]],
        tail: Case[T, L]) // What is the return type here???)
    = at[H :+: T, L]((c, l) =>
        c match {
          case Inl(h) => PolyEval(h, l)
          case Inr(t) => PolyEvalCop(t, l)
      })
  }
}
```

Console session:

```
scala> import shapeless._, CoproductSample._
import shapeless._
import CoproductSample._

scala> case class Foo(i: Int); case class Bar(s: String)
defined class Foo
defined class Bar

scala> val f = (foo: Foo) => foo.copy(i = foo.i * 2)
f: Foo => Foo = <function1>

scala> val g = (bar: Bar) => bar.copy(s = bar.s + "_changed!")
g: Bar => Bar = <function1>

scala> val hl = accum(g, accum(f, HNil))
hl: shapeless.::[Bar => Bar,shapeless.::[Foo => Foo,shapeless.HNil.type]] = <function1> :: <function1> :: HNil

scala> type C = Foo :+: Bar :+: CNil
defined type alias C

scala> PolyEvalCop(Coproduct[C](Foo(10)), hl)
res1: Any = Some(Foo(20))

scala> PolyEvalCop(Coproduct[C](Bar("bar")), hl)
res2: Any = Some(Bar(bar_changed!))
```

The result type is not properly tracked and it's resolved as `Any`.

Comment: I might try to take a look later, but in the mean time, I recommend you to compile it with "-Xlog-implicits"

Answer (score 0):

From the signature of `addF` it looks like you want to map over the `Coproduct`, i.e. modify it's value and stay on a coproduct, i.e. `def add[E](e:E):E`, if that were the case this would work:

```
@ {
  trait Add[E]{
    def add(e:E):E
  }
  object Add{
    def apply[E:Add]:Add[E] = implicitly[Add[E]]
    implicit object cnil extends Add[CNil] {
     def add(e:CNil) = throw new RuntimeException("Impossible")
    }
    implicit def coproduct[H, T <: Coproduct](
                 implicit
                 addH: Add[H],
                 addT:Add[T],
                 basis: ops.coproduct.Basis[H :+: T,T]
                 ):Add[H :+: T] = new Add[H :+: T]{
        def add(e: H :+: T) = e match {
           case Inl(h) => Coproduct[H :+: T](addH.add(h)) // to stay in the Coproduct
           case Inr(t) => addT.add(t).embed[H :+: T] // to stay in the coproduct
         }
      }
  }
  }
defined trait Add
defined object Add
@ implicit def addString = new Add[String] {
     def add(e:String) = e + "-ah"
  }
defined function addString
@ implicit def addInt = new Add[Int] {
     def add(e:Int) = e + 1
  }
defined function addInt
@ type C = Int :+: String :+: CNil
defined type C
@ val i = Coproduct[C](1)
i: C = 1
@ Add[C].add(i)
res24: C = 2 // notice that the return type is C
@ val s = Coproduct[C]("a")
s: C = a
@ Add[C].add(s)
res26: C = a-ah // notice that the return type is C
```

It obviously works with "plain" types:

```
@ Add[Int].add(1)
res38: Int = 2
```

The above is equivalent to `map`; but if you want a `fold`, i.e. `def add[E](e:E):Int`, you would just modify these two lines:

```
case Inl(h) => addH.add(h)
case Inr(t) => addT.add(t)
```

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer. However, my intent is to give the user a helper method for adding plain functions, with its own logic, without having to deal with writing additional typeclasses for custom algebras. I can't see how to reach this goal with your typeclass based approach. In fact, it's similar to one of my first attempts that led me to try with generic derivation of typeclasses.

Comment: Please, take into account that the users of my API will work with its own types and I don't want them having to deal with the burden of writing advanced code but simple plain monomorphic functions. That's the reason why I'm looking for a solution that accumulates functions on a HList that will enable to fold coproduct values afterwards.

Comment: I see, nevertheless, I think I remember reading miles discouraging poly functions, since as you can see they are basically ad-hoc type-classes... did you compile your example with `-Xlog-implicits`?

Comment: Yes! I compiled with `-Xlog-implicits` and that helped a lot. Thanks!. I'll publish an update later with my current solution that almost works.